# how to get my code in this compiler to look like this in chrome?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, console.log

[so this compiler is getting my code out correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxaF6.png)
I am using programiz to get this

but when I try and run it in chromes console it outputs it like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpruv.png)
my question is how do I get chrome's console.log to look like the compilers one?

here's my [html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HShZ.png) if it is needed.

sorry if this is an easy/stupid question I'm new to this.

Comment: Use `console.log(JSON.stringify(filtered))`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.